# Connectivity between php and oracle

Tags: php, oracle9i

I am working in php. Can you please suggest on how to do connectivity between Oracle 9i and php? I have to connect it with oracle 9i, not MySQL.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look here:  http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-oci.connection.php

Comment: There is also [OCI8](http://php.net/manual/de/ref.oci8.php).